# Discord.js - I'am trying to create a discord bot that mutes all connected members in a voicechannel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to create a discord bot that mutes all members of a certain voicechannel, the program executes without error but nothing happens.

```
        let among_us_channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === '751440430847098934');
        let group_of_channels = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === '599377349531795471');
        const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.parentID === '599377349531795471' && c.type === 2);


        for (const [channelID, channel] of channels) {
            for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
                member.VoiceState.setMute(true, 'Game Started');
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try changing `VoiceState` to `voice`

Comment: Hello @AksJacoves I tried to change `VoiceState` to `voice`, but the outcome hasnt changed i'm afraid, do you have any other suggestions? 
Best regards, Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention was to mute everyone of a single channel and you don't mind hard coding it's id. Then it is as easy as that:

```js
// Gets The Channel
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(`channelId`);

// Iterate through it's members
channel.members.forEach(member => {
  member.voice.setMute(true); // Mute em'
});
```

Whatever, it looks like you're trying to mute every channel from a category. If that's the  case, try this:

```js
// Get the children of the category
const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.get(`categoryId`).children;

// Iterate through then
channels.forEach(channel => {
  if(channel.type === 'voice') {          // check if it is a voice channel
    channel.members.forEach(member => {   // Iterate through it's members
      member.voice.setMute(true);         // Mute em'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the first one you gave me that worked, I really apprieciate it, you have helped an aspiring programmer today, I hope you the best in the world.

Comment: No problem. It means a lot to me, good luck there buddy.

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has no property called `VoiceState`, but [`voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice), which is a [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState).

---

```js
for (const [channelID, channel] of channels) {
    for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
        member.voice.setMute(true, 'Game Started');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Jakye, thanks for the quick reply, I tried changing the `VoiceState` to `voice`, and it haven't changed the outcome, do you have any other ideas as to why it might not work?

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: Hello. Are you getting any error(s) in the console?

Comment: No, i'am still not getting any errors, it is the exact same result i'm afraid.
It only prints my checker line saying `Ready!`, when it is run.
Do you think it could have something to do with my **index.js** file?